# Creating an efficient texture recoloring fragment shader

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I'm trying to create a fragment shader to recolor a 2D grayscale sprite but leave white and near-white fragments intact (ie: don't recolor pure white fragments, and only slightly recolor near-white fragments).  I'm not sure how to do this without using a conditional branch which results in poor performance on certain hardware.

The existing shader in the game engine just performs a simple multiplication:

```
#ifdef GL_ES                                
precision lowp float;                       
#endif                                      

varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;               
varying vec2 v_texCoord;                    
uniform sampler2D CC_Texture0;              

void main()                                 
{                                           
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_texCoord);     
    gl_FragColor = texColor * v_fragmentColor; 
}
```

I think that in order to avoid the conditional, I need some sort of continuous mathematical function that will recolor fragments with RGB values greater than, say, (0.9, 0.9, 0.9) less than it would for fragments which are less than (0.9, 0.9, 0.9).

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this: Calculate the fully-recolored pixel, then mix with the original based on a function. Here's an idea:

```
vec4 texColor = texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_texCoord);

const vec4 kLumWeights = vec4(.2126, .7152, .0722, 0.0); // Rec. 709 luminance weights
float luminance = dot (texColor, kLumWeights);

vec4 recolored = texColor * v_fragmentColor;

const float kThreshold = 0.8;
float mixAmount = (luminance - kThreshold) / (1.0 - kThreshold); // Everything below kThreshold becomes 0, and from kThreshold to 1.0 becomes 0 to 1.0
mixAmount = clamp (mixAmount, 0.0, 1.0);
gl_FragColor = mix (recolored, texColor, mixAmount);
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It appears to still be re-coloring white fragments to the value in recolored, though I'm not sure why because the dot product of kLumWeights and (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) is equal to 1, as expected.  And so mixAmount should be equal to 1 as well and glFragColor should then be equal to texColor -- unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: Odd. It seems to work for me. What happens if you set texColor to something like `v_texCoord.x / 200.0;`? That should replace your input image with a 200 pixel wide black to white gradient. Then you can see if it's doing what you expect across brightness levels. Maybe also try changing the cut-off. Instead of 0.9 (and a multiplier of 10.0), maybe use 0.8 and a multiplier of 5.

Comment: I've changed the threshold to be a constant in the program above. You can pass it in as a parameter, or hard-code it, but try some lower values and see if it does what you want.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it actually does work. (was using an outdated sprite)  My only remaining issue with it now is that setting the kThreshold too high leaves too many light grey values being recolored but setting it too low will leave the image looking a bit "washed out" as more grey is preserved.  I suppose that's the trade-off that is made here.  Maybe altering the mixAmount function to be less linear will help with that.  Thanks a lot for a great answer